# Reading a binary serialized file without knowing the class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

If I have binary serialized a .NET object (lets say object of class Employee) into a file. Now, some other smart urchin decides to de-serialize that file using a .NET app but he does not know the file is the Employee object serialized. Will he be able to read the data from that file till he does not know the class, the object of which was serialized? If yes, how?

PS - I am guessing we can take data into a byte array and then use it, I just know how will we read the values of the properties of the employee class.

Answer (score 1):

A binary serialized object can only be deserialized if you "know the class", as this is part of the serialized data.

If you do not have that class available in your application you can not deserialize that object using a binary serializer.
You can alwasy read the data as `byte[]`, but parsing that could be very hard.

Can you explain your "bigger picture" where you need such logic - may there is a better solution.

In general if you want to read the data without the serialized class you should use another serialization mode like XML.

Comment: the bigger picture is to read a binary file I have on my machine. I am able to load it in the byte array but since I do not know its class, I am not able to read the property values. Sounds like an interesting problem to solve!

Comment: So the data is generated by another program and you want to read it?

Comment: It's the exact same problem that programmers faced when having to **guess** the structure of a binary file created using an application which source code was lost.

Comment: If it is a .NET app there is no need to guess - just use a decompiler like ILSpy...

Answer (score 0):

The file can be deserialized, if the other application has the same class defined.

The class will be determined using the fully qualified name. So the class should have the same name, namespace and assembly.

If this is a strong typed assembly, the version should be the same as well.